# Inconsistent data type for DATE

Tags: date, ignite

I wish to store some data containing dates, like "2023-06-05", I use binary object to build and insert each row into my cache in ignite. Since ignite supports "java.sql.Date" type, I register the data as this type.

```
queryEntity.addQueryField(field, "java.sql.Date");
```

However, when I use thin client to retreie them, the date value is "java.util.Date" type, which is inconsistent with what I defined for the table schema.

```
SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(queryString);

try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql)) {
  for (List<?> row : cursor) {
    row.forEach(val -> {
      log.info(val.getClass().getName()); // this prints "java.util.Date"
      .....
}
```

My question is how to store and retreive date with "java.sql.Date" type, or this is an expected behaviour for ignite.

Comment: Once I also met such behaviour. Had to accept that as a fact. Not sure, but as I remember with LocalDate/Time there was no such inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for replying, do you mean 'java.time.LoaclTime'? I tried this type instead of date but still get 'java.util.Date' when querying, I think timestamp is the only consistent datetime type

Comment: I'm assuming you originally set java.util.Date and then changed the cache config to java.sql.Date. In this case, the cache configuration will still use java.util.Date because the configuration is saved to disk after the cache is created and is immutable. Could you please confirm that you are using correct class from the begging? Could you please destroy the cache and create it one more time with the correct type and test one more time? Please be sure that first object you put inside also will be java.sql.Date.

Comment: yes I put java.sql.Date at the beginning, I dont import java.util.Date anywhere in my project, but when query the rows, I print their class name and it shows java.util.Date